# Ajax sends request more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a huge problem with working with AJAX:
After the AJAX request on my page is send the next request are send multiple times, and buttons think that they are pressed multiple times. 
Now I searched around here and the internet, but I can't solve it. So far, following corrections are made in the code:

- All code is in an own function called AjaxInit()
- AjaxInit() is called upon $(window).load and on $(document).ajaxStop
- All Element have their binder to body (e.g. $("body").on("click","#btn-main", function)

Now I have tried unbinding all events using $("body").find("*").off(), but that did not help either. 
I know that I do something wrong, I just don't know what. 
How can I properly rebind everythink after the Ajax call is done? How can I make shure that object bindings (e.g. $("#news").sortable({})) will work properly after the first ajax call? 
 I would love to use AJAX for all the callbacks on my page, but currently the best solution seems to be just reloading the entire page after every ajax call, which would be rather bad.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Code added

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  AjaxInit();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  AjaxInit();
});

function AjaxInit() {
  $("body").on("click", "#btn-admin-main", function(e) {
    console.log("Admin clicked");
    e.handled = true;
    e.preventDefault();
    LoadDynamicContent("/Edit/");
  });


}

function LoadDynamicContent(path) {
  //Nach oben Scrollen
  $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: path,
    success: function(response) {
      var html_response = $(response).find('#dynamic_content').html();
      $("#dynamic_content").html(html_response);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sidebutton-full" id="btn-main">Edit</a>
<div id="dynamic_content"></div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are adding event listeners to some buttons after each ajax request. You need to provide relevant code as per [mcve]

Comment: Share some code to support your error.

Comment: Code added. Weird thing i just found out: Even if I don't do ANYTHING in the sucess block, it still fired the event twice the next time

Comment: possible issue is that you included jquery twice .. or some other library

Comment: I don't think so, no.
Is there a way to simply rebind all listeners?

Comment: try this , it may help you $(document).unbind('click').on("click", "#btn-main", function () {


        });

Comment: okay, that worked halfway. Now the button is firing the event only once everytime (thanks). But i somehow get the submit event twice? Here is my Code for submitting:
    $(document).off("click", "#btn-news").on("click", "#btn-news", function () {
        $("#form_news_sort").submit();
    });

This get's called only once, but $("#form_news_sort").submit() fires twice. How can i unbind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unbind the click event from button

```
$(document).unbind('click').on("click", "#btn-main", function () {
 //do stuff here
});
```

OR

```
$(document).off("click", "#btn-news").on("click", "#btn-news", function () { 

 });
```

If your form submission hitting twice then you need to change your code little bit

```
$("#form_news_sort").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    // do stuffer here
    .
    .
    .
    .
    return false;
 })
```

if you are still facing error , please comment below

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly. Sometimes it's just the small thinks :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when your `ajaxStop` handler calls `AjaxInit()`, it adds another click handler to the body.

In your example code, it looks like you don't need `ajaxStop` at all. All it will do is add another click handler, which is the problem. Or if your real code does some more complex initialization that needs to run whenever all Ajax requests are complete, you should factor out the click handler assignment from whatever else needs to happen.